# Sequence of functions that approach min at the limit?

Tags: functional-analysis

This is a bit of a loose, explorative question. I think it could still have pretty straightforward answers, but I apologize if it's more of a discussion question than a question with a single good answer.

Given the function sequence $f_p(x, y) = \sqrt[p]{\lvert x \rvert^p + \lvert y \rvert^p}$ we get that $\lim\limits_{p \to \infty} f_p = max$.

I'm wondering if there is any sort of "morally equivalent" construction for $min$? Even if not in a general context, for instance, if we have to restrict to non-negative reals or a compact domain to make it work, I would be interested to know.

Comment: Note that your function only works on non-negative inputs. For positive reals (or non-negative if you do your arithmetic in $[0, \infty]$ in the sensible way), you can just take $p \to -\infty$, related to the fact that $\min(x, y) = [\max(x^{-1}, y^{-1})]^{-1}$. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Special_cases).